# How can I get specific elements that are inside a div?

Tags: php, html, xpath

I am looking to extract a full div which I have been able to extract from the rest of the source code. From that div, I want all the html content as is, but without some of the child div inside.
HTML code to query:

```html
<div class="content"> 
    <div class="article-title"> 
        <h2>Title of the test</h2> 
        <a href="http://www.helloworld.com" title="post by world" rel="author" class="article-icon"><span class="text-icon">&#x1F464;</span>world</a>
        <span class="article-icon">
            <span class="text-icon">&#x1F4C1;</span> 
                <a href="http://www.helloworld.com/world">world</a>, 
            </span> 
            <span class="article-icon"><span class="text-icon">&#x1F554;</span>20.August 2014
        </span> 
    </div> 
    <p class="p1">
        <span class="s1"><b>a test</b></span>
    </p>  
    <p class="p2">
        <span class="s1">text2</span>
    </p> 
    <p class="p1">
        <span class="s1"><b><a href="http://www.helloworld.com/hello.jpg">
            <img class="alignright size-medium wp-image-19472" src="http://www.helloworld.com/hello.jpg" alt="hello" width="300" height="218"></a>Hello</b>
        </span>
    </p>  
    <p class="p1">
        <span class="s1"><b>text text text</b></span>
    </p> 
    <p class="p1">
        <span class="s1"><b><a href="http://www.helloworld.com/hello2.jpg">
            <img class="alignleft size-medium wp-image-19474" src="http://www.helloworld.com/hello2.jpg" alt="hello2" width="300" height="200"></a>Hello2</b>
        </span>
    </p> 
    <p class="p1">
        <span class="s1">text1</span>
    </p> 
    <p class="p1">
        <span class="s1">text2</span>
    </p> 
    <p class="p1">
        <span class="s1"><b>Final thoughts</b></span>
    </p> 
    <p class="p1">
        <span class="s1">testing (<a href="http://www.helloworld.com/test">
            <span class="s2">test</span></a>, 
            <a href="http://www.helloworld.com/test2">
            <span class="s2">test2</span></a>
        </span>
    </p> 
    <p class="p1">
        <span class="s1">***</span>
    </p> 
    <p class="p5"><em>
        <span class="s1">xyz <a href="http://www.helloworld.com/xyz">
            <span class="s2">123</span></a> (at <a href="http://www.helloworld.com">
            <span class="s2">http://www.helloworld.com</span></a>. &#xA0;
        </span></em>
    </p> 
    <div class="panel-breaking-line"></div> 
    <div class="article-tags"> <b>Tags added to this article</b> 
        <div class="tagcloud"> <a href="http://www.helloworld.com/world">world</a><a href="http://www.helloworld.com/xyz">zyx</a> </div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="panel-breaking-line"></div> 
    <div class="article-socials"> <b>Share this article with friends</b> 
        <div class="social-likes"> 
            <div class="soc-button soc-button-facebook"> <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.helloworld.com/world" data-url="http://www.helloworld.com/world" class="soc-click ot-share">
                <span class="text-icon">&#xF30C;</span>FACEBOOK</a>
                <span class="likes-count">
                    <span class="count">0</span>
                    <span class="bullet">&#xA0;</span>
                </span> 
                </div> 
                <div class="soc-button soc-button-twitter"> <a href="#" class="soc-click ot-tweet" data-hashtags="" data-url="http://www.helloworld.com/world" data-via="" data-text="World">
                    <span class="text-icon">&#xF309;</span>TWITTER</a>
                    <span class="likes-count">
                        <span class="count">0</span>
                        <span class="bullet">&#xA0;</span>
                    </span> 
                </div> 
                <div class="soc-button soc-button-pinterest"> <a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://www.helloworld.com/world" data-url="http://www.helloworld.com/world" class="ot-pin soc-click">
                <span class="text-icon">&#xF312;</span>PINTEREST</a>
                <span class="likes-count">
                    <span class="count">0</span>
                    <span class="bullet">&#xA0;</span>
                </span> 
            </div> 
            <div class="soc-button soc-button-google"> <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.helloworld.com/world" class="ot-pluss soc-click">
                <span class="text-icon">&#xF30F;</span>GOOGLE+</a>
                <span class="likes-count">
                    <span class="count">0</span>
                    <span class="bullet">&#xA0;</span>
                </span> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

So basiccaly, I want all the content class html, but without the elements that have class="article-title", class="article-socials" and class="article-tags"

so it would get stripped down to:

```html
<div class="content"> 
    <p class="p1">
        <span class="s1"><b>a test</b></span>
    </p>  
    <p class="p2">
        <span class="s1">text2</span>
    </p> 
    <p class="p1">
        <span class="s1"><b><a href="http://www.helloworld.com/hello.jpg">
            <img class="alignright size-medium wp-image-19472" src="http://www.helloworld.com/hello.jpg" alt="hello" width="300" height="218"></a>Hello</b>
        </span>
    </p>  
    <p class="p1">
        <span class="s1"><b>text text text</b></span>
    </p> 
    <p class="p1">
        <span class="s1"><b><a href="http://www.helloworld.com/hello2.jpg">
            <img class="alignleft size-medium wp-image-19474" src="http://www.helloworld.com/hello2.jpg" alt="hello2" width="300" height="200"></a>Hello2</b>
        </span>
    </p> 
    <p class="p1">
        <span class="s1">text1</span>
    </p> 
    <p class="p1">
        <span class="s1">text2</span>
    </p> 
    <p class="p1">
        <span class="s1"><b>Final thoughts</b></span>
    </p> 
    <p class="p1">
        <span class="s1">testing (<a href="http://www.helloworld.com/test">
            <span class="s2">test</span></a>, 
            <a href="http://www.helloworld.com/test2">
            <span class="s2">test2</span></a>
        </span>
    </p> 
    <p class="p1">
        <span class="s1">***</span>
    </p> 
    <p class="p5"><em>
        <span class="s1">xyz <a href="http://www.helloworld.com/xyz">
            <span class="s2">123</span></a> (at <a href="http://www.helloworld.com">
            <span class="s2">http://www.helloworld.com</span></a>. &#xA0;
        </span></em>
    </p> 
    <div class="panel-breaking-line"></div> 
    <div class="panel-breaking-line"></div> 
</div>
```

With or without the content div definition...

I have try many expression and I have come down to this:

```
//This is working but returning all content of the div

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $elements = @$xpath->query(".");
    foreach ($elements as $element) 
        $results .= $element->ownerDocument->saveHTML($element);
    }
```

Then with this expression instead of just the dot:

```
    div[@class='content']/*[not(contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), 'article-title')) and not(contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), 'article-social')) and not(contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), 'article-tags'))]
```

It does not return me anything, any idea how I can get this thing to work?

Comment: You only need to add leading `//` : `//div[@class='content']/*[not(contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), 'article-title')) and not(contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), 'article-social')) and not(contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), 'article-tags'))]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just explicitly put them on the `not(contains())`

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadHTML($markup);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$elements = $xpath->query('
//div[@class="content"]/*[
    not(contains(@class, "article-title")) and
    not(contains(@class, "article-socials")) and
    not(contains(@class, "article-tags"))
]
');

$html = '';
foreach ($elements as $child) {
    $html .= $dom->saveXML($child);
}

echo htmlentities($html);
```

[Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/gwt1in)

Comment: that worked except for some reason I had to remove the htmlentities function....not sure why!